# Online gallery software that has good integration with lightroom 6

Tags: photo-management, photo-galleries

I'm looking for online gallery software that has good integration with lightroom 6.

My prerequisites:

- Easy publishing from within Lightroom 6 with e.g. a plugin
- software should be installable on my own personal server and be served as a subdomain of my personal website, like: http://photos.example.com
- Tags, including people-tags and geotags should be exported. In the gallery, you should be able to easily search on any tag, person's name or location
- access control: the site is intended for family pictures, so only family members get a password and should be granted access.
- Makes use of modern HTML5/CCS3/responsive web design. Since the intended audience is quite small (my immediate family), I don't care if older browsers aren't supported.

[Koken](http://koken.me/) looked like the perfect solution I was looking for, but recently [the developers announced that they are moving on to other projects](https://medium.com/vantage/we-re-selling-koken-e1193c019f2f), so the continued support for the product looks very unsure.

Do you have any recommendations similar to Koken?

Comment: Are you stuck on these requirements? Because you can build anything you want with Joomla or Wordpress, but you'll need to do the programming.

Maybe consider a hosted service instead.

Comment: We have _never_ had good results here with people giving a long list of very specific software requirements. You might try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com (after [reading their guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 2):

Is there something that Lr's existing web publishing module can't handle? It's kinda basic, and you'd have to work out access control via your chosen web construction software, but it just works.

There are also WordPress/LR solutions; see http://apps.meow.fr/wplr-sync/ eg.

Or perhaps this: http://terrywhite.com/built-photography-website-lightroom-ttg/